# tikz prevent label from overwriting edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

The following code draws a simple graph with 4 nodes. Unfortunately the labels overwrite/overlap the arrows (I have marked with circles two of the problem areas.)

How can I prevent a label from overwriting these arrows?

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, patterns, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [scale=0.6,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=black!20, minimum size=2.5em}]
    \tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=circle,draw,minimum size=1.5em}}
    \tikzset{>={Latex[length=2.5mm]}}

    \node (s) at (0,5){s};
    \node (v1) at (6,9){1};
    \node (v2) at (6,1){2};
    \node (t) at (12,5){t};

    \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->}}
    \Edge[label=$1/10^6$, color=red](s)(v1);
    \Edge[label=$1/10^6$](s)(v2);
    \Edge[label=$1/1$, color=red](v1)(v2);
    \Edge[label=$1/10^6$](v1)(t);
    \Edge[label=$1/10^6$, color=red](v2)(t);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Labels are also nodes so they inherit `minimum size` of `every node` style. Use `every label/.style={minimum size=1pt}` to override (somewhere after `every node`)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add to your code the parts that missing to be a full compilable code. (from `\documentcalss` to `\end{document}` with the libraries and definitions needed to be a full working example)

Comment: Please provide a fully working minimal example (MWE).

Comment: @koleygr Added the missing code for a working minimal example. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is definition of style `every node/.style={...}`. it also define style of labels. if you delete it and for nodes uses `vertex`, your diagram become fine.

with exploiting of tikz library `positioning` your code is:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, patterns, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [auto=left,
     node distance=28 mm and 50mm,
%     every node/.style={circle,fill=black!20, minimum size=2.5em},
    vertex/.style = {shape=circle,draw,fill=black!20,minimum size=2.5em},
    EdgeStyle/.style={-{Latex[length=2.5mm]}}
    ]

    \node[vertex]                   (s)  {s};
    \node[vertex,above right=of s]  (v1) {1};
    \node[vertex,below right=of s]  (v2) {2};
    \node[vertex,above right=of v2] (t)  {t};

    \Edge[label=$1/10^6$, color=red](s)(v1);
    \Edge[label=$1/10^6$](s)(v2);
    \Edge[label=$1/1$, color=red](v1)(v2);
    \Edge[label=$1/10^6$](v1)(t);
    \Edge[label=$1/10^6$, color=red](v2)(t);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, patterns, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
        scale=0.6, 
        auto=left, 
        customNode/.style={shape = circle, fill = black!20, minimum size = 2.5em}
    ]
    \tikzset{>={Latex[length=2.5mm]}}

    \node [customNode] (s) at (0,5){s};
    \node [customNode] (v1) at (6,9){1};
    \node [customNode] (v2) at (6,1){2};
    \node [customNode] (t) at (12,5){t};

    \draw[->, color = red] (s) -- node [midway] {$1/10^6$} (v1);
    \draw[->] (s) -- node [midway] {$1/10^6$}(v2);
    \draw[->, color = red] (v1) -- node [midway] {$1/1$} (v2);
    \draw[->] (v1) -- node [midway] {$1/10^6$} (t);
    \draw[->, color = red] (v2) -- node [midway] {$1/10^6$} (t);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that automates `\Edge` command to be easier in usage:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, patterns, arrows.meta}

\let\oldEdge\Edge
\renewcommand{\Edge}[4][\empty]{\ifx{[#1]}\empty\oldEdge(#3)(#4);\else\draw[->, color = #2] (#3) -- node [midway,color=black] {#1} (#4);\fi}%\oldEdge[](#2)(#3)node[midway]{#1};\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [scale=0.6,auto=left,every node/.style={circle,fill=black!20, minimum size=2.5em}]
    \tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=circle,draw,minimum size=1.5em}}
    \tikzset{>={Latex[length=2.5mm]}}   
    \node (s) at (0,5){s};
    \node (v1) at (6,9){1};
    \node (v2) at (6,1){2};
    \node (t) at (12,5){t};

    \tikzset{every node/.style={circle,minimum size=1em}}
    \Edge[$1/10^6$]{red}{s}{v1};
    \Edge{black}{s}{v2};
    \Edge[$1/1$]{red}{v1}{v2};
    \Edge[$1/10^6$]{black}{v1}{t};
    \Edge[$1/10^6$]{red}{v2}{t};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I failed to use \Edge with custom node and used `\draw` command like @Sam.

I just redefined `every node` style before using it in `\Edge` command.

\Edge can be left without optional argument for no label.